# Can't run the SPRING BOOT application with @EnableWebMvc configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I'm new to spring boot and i'm very much interested to learn this technology. Here is the issue,  I got one configuration file with @configuration tag. so i can't run the application when i try to add @enablemvc annotation or if i add new file with @enablemvc annoation in the spring boot application. i really appreciate if some one can help me with thisss.

log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init ResourceHttpRequestHandler; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [resources/], class path resource [images/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@39e6b948]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19b44076: startup date [Sat Feb 10 09:34:19 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.configureAsChildIfNecessary(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:147) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:130) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.boot.main.ClientMain.main(ClientMain.java:31) [bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init ResourceHttpRequestHandler; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [resources/], class path resource [images/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@39e6b948]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19b44076: startup date [Sat Feb 10 09:34:19 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init ResourceHttpRequestHandler; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [resources/], class path resource [images/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@39e6b948]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19b44076: startup date [Sat Feb 10 09:34:19 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.getHandlerMapping(ResourceHandlerRegistry.java:150) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:446) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c7bc0fe.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$28(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c7bc0fe$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d042f6eb.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c7bc0fe.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [resources/], class path resource [images/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@39e6b948]]] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19b44076: startup date [Sat Feb 10 09:34:19 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:112) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getServletContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.initContentNegotiationStrategy(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:306) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.afterPropertiesSet(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:268) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.getHandlerMapping(ResourceHandlerRegistry.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

AutoConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnClass(MyClass.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
@ComponentScan({ "com.boot", "com.jspClient" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class AutoConfiguration {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AutoConfiguration.class);




    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    /*@Bean  
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver() {  
      UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");  
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
      return resolver;  
    }*/


    //http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/simple-mapping-exception-resolver/
    //https://github.com/paulc4/mvc-exceptions/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/config/ExceptionConfiguration.java
    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
      SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
      Properties errorMaps = new Properties();
      errorMaps.setProperty(UserNotFoundException.class.getName(), "myError");
      errorMaps.setProperty("Exception", "generic_error");
      resolver.setExceptionMappings(errorMaps);
      resolver.setDefaultErrorView("generic_error");
      resolver.setExceptionAttribute("exc");
      return resolver;
   }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                ResourceHandlerRegistration resourceRegistration  = registry
                        .addResourceHandler("/pages/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/resources/","classpath:/images/")  //Configuring Multiple Locations for a Resource
                        .setCachePeriod(3600);            //The resources served will be cached in the browser for 3600 seconds
                registry.addResourceHandler("resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
                //registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
                //registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
                //registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("com.boot.controllers") 
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
      SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
      Properties errorMaps = new Properties();
      errorMaps.setProperty("ElectricityNotFoundException", "error");
      errorMaps.setProperty("NullPointerException", "error");
      resolver.setExceptionMappings(errorMaps);
      resolver.setDefaultErrorView("globalerror");
      resolver.setExceptionAttribute("exc");
      return resolver;
   }
}
```

WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
   }  
}
```

ClientMain.java

```
@ComponentScan("com.boot") // to scan controller under com.boot -> com.boot.controllers
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientMain {

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder start(Class<?>... sources) {
        return new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientMain.class)
            .child(sources);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // using just Spring alone
        /*ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AutoConfiguration.class);

    }

}
```

JspClientMain.java

```
@ComponentScan("com.boot") 
@SpringBootApplication
public class JspClientMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JspClientMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps related https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases

Comment: The [documentation explains why you should or not use the annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters).

Answer (score 5):

In general, the **`@EnableWebMvc` should not be used in Spring boot applications**.  I quote an [article by Boz Hogan](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases):

> It turns out that Spring Boot doesn’t mix well with the standard Spring MVC `@EnableWebMvc`. What happens when you add the annotation is that Spring Boot's autoconfiguration is disabled.
>
> The bad part (that wasted me a few hours) is that in no guide you can find that explicitly stated. (...)

Here's a quote from the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration):

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers, and other features), you can add your own `@Configuration` class of type `WebMvcConfigurer` but **without** `@EnableWebMvc`. (...)
>
> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your own `@Configuration` annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`.

So, to use `@EnableWebMvc` in a Spring Boot app, you need to take **complete control** of Spring MVC—I read that as *you need to be a Spring wiz*.

We had a problem with a Spring boot 1.5.9 application that had a dependency to a shared lib that contained a class annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`. Removing the annotation solved the problem.

Comment: While the article discust not using it, it does not implies that it should not be used. Even worse, the article does not provide another way to acheive what the annotation does without using it.

Comment: The [documentation explains a lot better the why you should or not use the annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Please note that the answer is about using `@EnableWebMvc` in a **Spring Boot** application. Even the Spring documentation says you should add interceptors etc. **without** `@EnableWebMvc`. In any case, I updated the answer to add the relevant quotes. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is caused by mixing two different kind of initializers i.e WebApplicationInitializer and ApplicationContextInitializer.

Both WebApplicationInitializer and ApplicationContextInitializer serve fairly different purposes. 
The **WebApplicationInitializer** is used by a Servlet Container at startup of the web application and provides a way for programmatic creating a web application(replacement for a web.xml file),

**ApplicationContextInitializer** provides a hook to configure the Spring application context before it gets fully created.
For a non spring boot application/normal spring mvc app it is programmatic configuration of web.xml. like you have done in your code in WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws 
     ServletException {  
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(); 

            ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new 
            DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
   }  
}
```

**ApplicationContextInitializer** is essentially code that gets executed before the Spring application context gets completely created. A good use case for using an ApplicationContextInitializer would be to set a Spring environment profile programmatically, along these lines.

For Spring-Boot based application then registering an ApplicationContextInitializer could be done like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SampleWebApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new SpringApplicationBuilder(SampleWebApplication.class)
    .initializers(new DemoApplicationContextInitializer())
    .run(args);
 }
}

public class DemoApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

 @Override
 public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ac) {
  ConfigurableEnvironment appEnvironment = ac.getEnvironment();
  appEnvironment.addActiveProfile("demo");

 }
}
```