# A non-disruptive method of adding a static resource directory to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to make Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat to serve static contents from a directory specified by an absolute path `/path`. I know two methods: via `application.properties` or programmatically, but they both seem to have side effects. The first method:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/path
```

adds `/path` as requested, but removes (at least) all `src/main/resources/resources` from any Maven project involved. I could complete the above with

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/path,file:src/main/resources/resources
```

but it adds only `src/main/resources/resources` from the main project, not the respective directories having the same relative path in libraries.

Then, there is [programmatic approach](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }
}
```

but it uses `@EnableWebMvc` which [is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591404/8564676). Another programmatic approach [uses resource handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25705730/8564676) but then there is again `@EnableWebMvc`. These example also contains paths which look relative, like `/WEB-INF/classes/content/`, but they start with a slash anyway, which poses the question how to add an absolute path.

**Is there a method of *non-disruptive adding* of an absolute directory with static resources to Spring Boot?**